# Popup incoming calling Fullscreen like whatsapp

Tags: android

I am currently working on WebRTC "voice" calling. However, i don't quite know how to do a popup fullscreen like whatsapp when an incoming web call coming. It can click to answer, etc.

The below is what i need:
[Whatsapp incoming voice calling screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBSgJ.png)

Comment: It's not popup, its Activity

Comment: Hi Mohit, its like when you killed whatsapp, someone call you, the "activity" will move up and cover all your screen and you won't touch it, right? Thanks for reply.

Comment: I didn't get it, what you are talking

Comment: Do you have any example for me to take a look? thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about FullScreenActivity?

Comment: thank you, i solved the problem now. I was thinking it might be something related to overlay popup notification.... But it finally turns out "quite simple". I have a boardcast receiver, then just call context.startActivity(new Intent(context, yourActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

Answer (score 0):

thank you, i solved the problem now. I was thinking it might be something related to overlay popup notification.... But it finally turns out "quite simple".

I have a boardcast receiver, then just call the following inside boardcast receiver:

```
public class callingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, OptimizationActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            }
        };
        thread.run();
}
```